# Get percentage of occurrences

Tags: mysql, sql, database, percentage

I have table (table_2) with following structure:

```
index, DATA2, ghost, PROJ
```

And query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE PROJ = "1" and ghost = "0"
```

And I am trying to get the percentage of how many rows have date set to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in column `DATA2`.

Comment: *I am trying to get percentage of how many rows have date set to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in column DATA2.* ```SELECT ... , SUM(DATA2 = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') OVER () / COUNT(*) OVER () AS needed_percentage FROM ...```. Needed percentage will present in each output row.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT ((COUNT(*) * 100) /
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2 WHERE PROJ = "1" AND ghost = "0")
       )
FROM table_2
WHERE PROJ = "1"
      AND ghost = "0"
      AND DATA2 = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Comment: This is solved.
Akina gave answer in comment.